# How do I install user theme extension in Gnome in Fedora 16?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

Upon going to [the user themes extension webpage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/), I get the following message:

```
This extension is incompatible with your version of GNOME. This extension supports the GNOME unstable release, 3.3.2
```

I have Gnome Version 3.2.1 according to System Info. So how would I go about installing the lastest unstable Gnome releases?

**EDIT**: I am running Fedora 16

**EDIT 2**: I would like to know if there is a repository to be installed so that I can simply `yum update` to the latest Gnome development version (downloading and installing gnome-shell-3.3.3 from [here](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/applications/Gnome%20Shell?_csrf_token=655af6343773bf38a7e1ec7110eaf4763bf17610) or [here](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/builds/show/F-devel-x86_64/gnome-shell/0/3.3.3/1.fc17/x86_64?_csrf_token=65d69c0fada2764c9bf46de7cdea7d5e695cce4c) gives me an error with a list of dependencies yet to be satisfied)

**EDIT 3**: I remember successfully installing gnome-shell-extension-user-theme via yum a few months ago that worked just fine with Gnome, anybody know how to install an older version of the extension that is compatible with Gnome 3.2?

Comment: Ok, I was even assuming the wrong distro altogether :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the latest GNOME Shell (sandboxed) using [JHBuild](http://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/unstable/getting-started.html.en) pretty easily, as explained [here](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell#Building).

Note that this doesn't care about which distribution you're using, so there might be another way, i.e., some Fedora analogue of using experimental packages on Debian, that I don't know of.  (I found [this 3.3.3-1 GNOME-Shell package](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/builds/show/F-devel-x86_64/gnome-shell/0/3.3.3/1.fc17/x86_64?_csrf_token=65d69c0fada2764c9bf46de7cdea7d5e695cce4c) as an indication that there *is* something like a devel package, but I don't know how to make use of it.)

Comment: Thanks for the info! It seems a bit less daunting to install from a repository than by building from source, so I'm going to try to find the repo first :)

Comment: While building from source might seem daunting, JHBuild really makes the whole thing easy as pie. (And sandboxed, i.e., you won't mess your system with it.)

Comment: It sounds nice, but I got frequent errors like `Error running ./autogen.sh --prefix /home/amosng/gnome-shell/install --libdir '/home/amosng/gnome-shell/install/lib64'  --disable-static --disable-gtk-doc` with a list of options like "Rerun phase build," etc. I tried ignoring the error or giving up on the module, neither seemed to have much effect. I managed to fixed everything in the sanitycheck too. Interestingly, I remember installing all this from yum without trouble a few months ago. I guess an update made it now require Gnome 3.3, which I admit I am about to give up installing :(